# How to define and use a Haskell-like sum type in Dhall

Tags: haskell, dhall

How can I define a sum type analogous to Haskell's sum types in the Dhall programming language?

For instance, if in Haskell I'd define

```
data SumProp = Option1 | Option2
```

My purpose is to define in Dhall a record in which one of its properties has a limited set of possible values:

```
\(sumPropValue : SumProp) -> { value = sumPropValue }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the standard way this is done is by creating a union type where each option's type is an empty record:

```
$ dhall > SumProp <<EOF
< option1 : {} | option2 : {} >
EOF
```

This type permits the values:

```
< option1 = {=} | option2 : {} >
< option2 = {=} | option1 : {} >
```

though you'll obviously want to name these something convenient like `option1` and `option2`:

```
$ dhall > option1 <<EOF
< option1 = {=} | option2 : {} >
EOF
$ dhall > option2 <<EOF
< option2 = {=} | option1 : {} >
EOF
```

This blog article by Gabriel Gonzalez [Typed Nix programming using Dhall](http://www.haskellforall.com/2017/01/typed-nix-programming-using-dhall.html)  includes an example, if you search for the definition of the type `OperatingSystem`.

Comment: [The dhall tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dhall-1.16.1/docs/Dhall-Tutorial.html#g:12) mentions a `constructors` keyword that can be used to generate the convenience constructors.